# Probability of picking a card randomly vs always picking the first card?

Tags: probability, card-games

I shuffle a deck of cards. Each card appears there only once. Now, I need to pick a card randomly. I can do this in two ways:

1. literally, pick a card somewhere in the beginning/middle/end of the deck randomly.
2. always pick the first card

Context: for many games, you start by picking a random card to determine various things: how to start, who starts etc.

My friend claims that these two ways yield the same result, essentially they are the same i.e. each card has an equal probability of being at the very first place in the deck since we are shuffling randomly.

I claim that:

1) it COULD only be the case IF we could ensure "universally equal" shuffling, meaning that based on the person's shuffling, some cards might never make it to the top,

2) since we do not have such "universally equal shuffling", the probabilities of the cards being picked are 1 for the first card, and 0 for all others; while if you randomly pick a card (way #1) the probabilities are indeed all equal to $1/52$ for each card (assuming there are 52 cards in the deck).

Where is the truth?

Comment: If the shuffling is biased then, to get a randomized selection, you do need to randomize the card you select.

Comment: If you are going to pick a card from a random position in the deck, then there's no need to shuffle. By the way, what method do you have in mind to randomize what card you pick?

Comment: What probsbility is ‘1 for the first card, and 0 for the others’...?

Comment: @Bram28 the probability to be picked if the second method is used (always pick the first card).

Comment: At the end of the selection procedure, whatever it is, the probability of being picked is always $1$ for the card you pick. The question is what is the probability of each card in the original deck to be the one picked. Regarding the bias of the shuffle, why not shuffle as usual, then pick a random point in the deck, cut the deck there, put the bottom part on top of the top part, and call that the last step of the shuffle? This gives you a shuffle whose top card is equivalent to one selected at random from a shuffled deck.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for formulating it better-yes, the question reduces to "can shuffling ensure that each card has an equal probability of appearing as the top card?" If not, then the two methods are not equal, in my opinion, but I need confirmation. What you are suggesting, cutting the deck and placing the picked card on top, is deviation from the question :) Initially, I am wondering if the two methods of picking the cards yield the same results. Based on comments, they do not.

Comment: @bof Those games require shuffling later on, so sometimes we shuffle as the very first step, but it could be treated as an independent step and done later, in my opinion, ONLY IF we pick the card according to method #1. Method #2 requires shuffling regardless of what happens next in the game, doesn't it? Otherwise, it can not ensure randomness in any way. And to answer your question, I do not have a specific method to randomize the card I pick, just picking ...randomly.

Comment: Do you play cards? In real card games, after one player shuffles, another player cuts the deck, creating a new top card. If it were possible to cut the deck randomly, this would amount to your method #1, no?

Comment: You can say it is “deviating from the question” to specify better shuffling. There are also two ways to perform a riffle shuffle, one of which keeps the top and bottom cards in place and the other of which tends to exchange inside and outside cards rapidly. Note that if you do a bad shuffle and then draw from the middle of the deck you will not draw the top card, so that card has zero chance and cards that started in the middle have more than $1/52$ chance.

Comment: @bof I realize this amounts to the method #1, since by cutting the deck randomly, you are essentially selecting a card. It doesn't matter what you do with it later(place at top, bottom, throw away etc) - you have selected the card already by cutting the deck. But while you randomly cut the deck in this case, in the case of method #2 you "non-randomly" always select the first card. Side note: I am not focused here on real card games, rather, on a problem of having n objects, and equality of ways to select a random object from it.